# Routing error after implementing bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-4

Creating a "Hack this site" as a fun project, but stumbled upon a routing error after adding the bootstrap gem, along with jquery.

app/assets/stylesheets/Application.scss

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

app/assets/javascripts/Application.js

```js
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Gem file

```rb
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
gem 'devise'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :pages, path: "", only: [] do
    collection do
      get :stage1
      get :stage2
      end
      end
  get 'resources/Videos'
  get 'resources/Photos'
  get 'layouts/home'
  root '_layouts#home'
  get "/pages/:page" => "pages#show"
  resources :posts
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Followed the Bootstrap-rubygem repository installation instructions, and ended up getting the following errors when trying to load the page.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"):
```

Got no clue as to what i have done wrong (Probably a lot of things), so i'd appreciate any answers that could lead to resolving this issue!

Comment: Have you restarted your server after installing the gems?

Comment: Yes, multiple times to no avail.

Comment: rename `Application.js` to `application.js` same way rename `Application.scss` to `application.scss`

Comment: Made no difference renaming the files.

Comment: Please show your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked for me (for now atleast).

Aparantly the application.scss had a subfile named application.css under it (using Jetbrains RubyMine).

Deleted the file application.css containing

```css
@import Bootstrap
```

And now its atleast loading the page properly with the bootstrap css, although the error messages are showing in the server terminal.

Will try to iron out the error messages and post it here if i find a solution to them.